# I'm trying to attach my SQL Server app to somee.com and I get an error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, somee

I'm trying to deploy an ASP.NET web app connected to a SQL Server database. I'm trying to attach the database by uploading the `.mdf` file but I always get an error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.
>   --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\dzsqls\krginventorydb2.mdf' is denied.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>   at DZWebSvc.DZWebAgent.AttachNewUserDBDataFileOnly(String DBName, String LoginName, String OriginalDBFileName, String OriginalLogFileName, String NewDBFileName, Int32 MaxDataFileSizeMB, Int32 MaxLogFileSizeMB, String ConnectionString, Boolean ChangeDefaultSchemaToDbo, String tk)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I am aware that I need to detach the db if it's currently active and so i did. The size of it is small enough to not exceed the maximum.  I don't know what's wrong. Help. :(

Comment: Does the user running the IIS site (IIS_IUSRS if unchanged) have access to the file or folder? If not, change the permissions.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, any solution? or did you solved that

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can deploy your database on somee.com by creating script of your database using Sql Server Managment Studio.
Please watch my video to resolve this error.

[Watch This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ_hPzJ1TAs)